# Circle with fluid/strechy stroke

Tags: ios, uibezierpath, cadisplaylink

Me and my team are working on an app for a client. We are trying to understand how to achieve this kind of animations (*refer only to the circle stroke*) :

[image]

We tried using a `CADisplayLink` to set up and change the circle, but it generated non-fluid results.
We couldn't find a way to create a circle from "components" of `UIBezierPath` and change each of the anchors.

**Any suggestions on how to achieve this kind of effect, or how to construct a circle from seperated points, would be highly appricated**

**Best Regards,**
**Roi and the team**

Comment: If someone is going to down vote, please have the dignity to comment why, As I don't see a reason why should it down voted.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I suggest using Catmull-Rom splines. Those allow you to create smooth curves using only points that are on the curve, whereas Bezier curves require that you define control points that are not on the curve.

Once you have beginning and ending `CGPath`s its pretty easy to create a `CAAnimation` of the path from it's starting to it's ending state (although animating change to a `CGPath` only works correctly if the starting and ending paths in the animation have the same number and type of points.)

You could probably also use Bezier curves, but you would need to generate the control points for the circle and it's distorted shape.

Check out this sample app that uses Catmull-Rom splines to create a distorted circle shape:

http://wareto.com/animating-shapes-using-cashapelayer-and-cabasicanimation

(Written in Objective-C, but the technique is the same in Swift.)

[image]

A Catmull-Rom spline with 8 control points evenly spaced around a circle where the distance from the center of each control points is varied by ± r/12 seems about right:

[image]

Comment: Perfect Duncan. Thank you for providing this answer. Much appreciated buddy.

Comment: Duncan, I actually spend a few good hours trying to convert your (great!) sample to what I wanted to achieve, It looks perfect! I'll be sure to send you a sample (if you'd like) when it's ready for release. Again thank you for your priceless help!

Comment: @RoiMulia I'd love to see it. Had you used CAAnimation before?

Comment: I did, but on far more simple tasks. By the way I have found a way to achieve this (partly) with UIBezierPath. You construct a circle from 4 arc, and to make the animations you change the control point with formula of sin(x) and cos(x). I'll make a project with the two solutions and send it over to you. Interesting approaches :)

Comment: Makes sense. With the work from my sample did you work with it in Objective-C or convert it to Swift? I have mountains of useful code I've written in Objective-C that I haven't found the time to convert, and this is just one example.

Comment: Roi, did you ever create a demo project showing your results?